# How to create a timeseries for the data which is collected every 1 hour with a time interval of 15 minutes

Tags: r, time-series

Data is available from (2019-01-01 00:00:00.0) to (2019-04-15 23:45:00.0)

I have tried this:

```
prodapt.ts.PmdAve <- ts(prodapt[,30], start = c(2019,1), frequency = 4)
```

I want time series on an hourly basis which is recorded with a time interval of 15 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Using `seq`:

```
start <- as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 00:00:00.000", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
end   <- as.POSIXct("2019-04-15 23:45:00.000", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
x <- seq(start, end, by=60*15)
x[c(1:10, (length(x)-9):length(x))]

 [1] "2019-01-01 00:00:00" "2019-01-01 00:15:00" "2019-01-01 00:30:00"
 [4] "2019-01-01 00:45:00" "2019-01-01 01:00:00" "2019-01-01 01:15:00"
 [7] "2019-01-01 01:30:00" "2019-01-01 01:45:00" "2019-01-01 02:00:00"
[10] "2019-01-01 02:15:00" "2019-04-15 21:30:00" "2019-04-15 21:45:00"
[13] "2019-04-15 22:00:00" "2019-04-15 22:15:00" "2019-04-15 22:30:00"
[16] "2019-04-15 22:45:00" "2019-04-15 23:00:00" "2019-04-15 23:15:00"
[19] "2019-04-15 23:30:00" "2019-04-15 23:45:00"
```